# Flex Spark tabbar : initialize hidden tabs

Tags: apache-flex, tabs, flex4, flex-spark

problem is I have a spark Tabbar, with many forms in each tab. 
But I have a single global save button. Problem is, if I don't open a Tab, 
it doesn't get initialized and therefore the forms it contains do not exist..

How Can I make it as if the user had clicked on every tab?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a TabBar just has stylized buttons ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-8000.html#WSed1ae4ff1d6fc04c40e2042a124f8a6d4f3-8000 ); and not hidden/embedded forms.  Can you you expand on your architecture? If you're using a ViewStack I believe you set creationPolicy to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to have a data model that each tab is displaying and editing, rather than trying to go in and read the values out of the controls in each tab, and save those.  This is at the heart of MVC.

However, if you're too invested in your current architecture to be able to change it and you are using a ViewStack with your TabBar, you may find that setting creationPolicy to "all" does what you want.  If you're using States, I don't think you can force all of them to be instantiated without putting your application into each State at least once.